# How to use OCMock to verify static methods

Tags: objective-c, unit-testing, ocmock

I am trying to use OCMock library. I am trying to create mock of class object, but it is failing to verify the method. I am unable to understand why the tests are failing.

```
@interface MyClass:NSObject
+(void) someMethod;
@end
@implementation MyClass
+(void) someMethod
{

    NSError* error = nil;
    if (![Utility isValidPropWithError:&error])
    {
        [Logger log:LoggerLevelWarning message:[error localizedDescription] className:className];
    }
}
@end
```

Test :

```
-(void)testIfLoggerIsset{
    id partialMockLogger = OCMClassMock([Logger class]);
    id partialMockUtility = OCMClassMock([Utility class]);
    id partialMockClass = OCMClassMock([MyClass class]);
    NSError *error = nil;
    OCMExpect([partialMockUtility isValidPropWithError:&error]);

    [MyClass someMethod];

    //This works fine.
    OCMVerifyAll(partialMockClass);
    NSString *className = @"classname";
    //This is failing...
    OCMVerify([partialMockUtility isValidPropWithError:&error]);
    OCMVerifyAll(partialMockUtility);
    //This is failing...
    OCMVerify([partialMockLogger log:LoggerLevelWarning message:[error localizedDescription] className:className]);
    [partialMockUtility stopMocking];
    [partialMockLogger stopMocking];
}
```

In the above code, although `[Utility isValidPropWithError:&error];` is called `OCMVerify([partialMockUtility isValidPropWithError:&error]);`is failing.

Answer (score 1):

Several things here:

First, `OCMVerify([partialMockUtility isValidPropWithError:&error]` is failing because you are expecting the address of the `NSError` object you created *in the test* to be passed to `isValidPropWithError:`, but in `MyClass +someMethod` you are creating a *different* `NSError` object. The addresses of two different objects will not be the same.

To fix this, change your expectation and verification to:

```
OCMExpect([partialMockUtility isValidPropWithError:(NSError __autoreleasing**)[OCMArg anyPointer]]);
OCMVerify([partialMockUtility isValidPropWithError:(NSError __autoreleasing**)[OCMArg
```

and just ignore the actual value of the parameter and expect that it's going to be an `NSError` pointer (since you're creating it inside of `someMethod`, there's no way to know what it's going to be before you call the method).

Second, since you are already explicitly verifying `+isValidPropWithError`, `OCMVerifyAll(partialMockUtility)` isn't going to verify anything. You should either explicitly verify all of your expectations, or simply use `OCMVerifyAll(partialMockUtility)` and let it verify all your expectations and don't bother with expecting the specific call. `OCMVerifyAll` will verify everything you expect on the mock object you give it. This isn't going to cause a test failure - both calls will pass, since you've already verified the call the first time, the call to `OCMVerifyAll()` isn't going to have anything to verify, so it will pass.

Last, `OCMVerify([partialMockLogger log:LoggerLevelWarning message:[error localizedDescription] className:className]);` is failing because you didn't set an expectation for it.